# Average over previous entries of Tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow I was wondering how you would take a tensor, say,

```
t1 = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, ...]
```

and output a tensor

```
t2 = [0, (a1)/2, (a1+a2)/2, (a2+a3)/2, (a3+a4)/2, ...]
```

So basically, the average of the previous two entries of the input tensor are the value for the output tensor, with some padding at the beginning of zeros. I would like to do this in a batch/vectorized fashion to save time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
t1 = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='float32')

# Adding two zeros to match your output
t1 = tf.concat([[0, 0], t1], axis=0)

res = (t1[:-1] + t1[1:])/2.0

print(res)
```

Gives

```
tf.Tensor([0.  1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much, I am surprised it was so easy. Technically it would be res = (t1[:-2] + t1[1:-1])/2.0 for the exact same as what I wrote for anyone who sees this, but the concept is perfect. Again, thank you very much.